# Updates in Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, updates

Currently i'm using Ubuntu 14.04 and it's very tempting that it shows updates every 2-3 days, so i have two solutions for now.

1. Select Show updates after a long time(i.e-1-2 weeks) so that it shows updates after a regular and long time interval.
2. Adjust the Settings so that it installes only the essential updates.

Currently i'm thinking about the 2nd option.

So I am thinking about how to configure my update settings so that it does not install **unwanted** updates.

It would be of great help if someone can tell me what are the important updates so that i can configure my settings.

Thanks.

Currently the options that i've selected are as follows.

**Ubuntu Software**

1. Canonical-supported free and open-source software(main).
2. Community-maintained free and open-source software(universe).
3. Proprietary drivers for devices(restricted).
4. Software restricted by copyright or legal issues(multiverse).

**Updates**

1. Important security updates(trusty-security).
2. Recommended updates(trusty-updates).

Comment: What do you consider to be "unwanter updates"?

Comment: Unwanted updates means the updates that are not necessary,
Such as updates for **music player, Gedit,** and  other apps that Ubuntu provides. While the **important** updates includes update for **kernel** and **security updates**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are different dimensions to the usual APT sources.

Firstly, there's the repository:

- main
- universe
- restricted
- multiverse

The choices of respository don't affect the importance of updates you receive, it just affects which software is supported.  You should have *all* of these selected, unless you know you are not using *any* software from one of these.

If you disable any of these, it effectively turns off all update support from any already-installed software you may have from that repository.

Secondly, there's the classification of update:

- -security
- -updates
- -proposed
- -backports

"-security" should always be enabled, because it contains important security updates.

"-updates" is optional but recommended.  It contains updates that may fix bugs but are not necessary for security patches.  You could disable it if you wanted fewer updates, but it tends to receive fewer updates than -security anyway.

"-proposed" should usually be disabled.  It contains updates that have not been officially approved.

"-backports" is a special one.  If you enable it, you gain the option of installing newer versions of installed software, but only if you do it manually.  If you never manually choose a software version from backports, you won't get any updates from it and having "-backports" source won't affect you, but if you do, it'll stay updated.

This is all a rather long-winded way of saying there's no magic bullet to reducing the number of package updates you receive.  The one viable option might be to disable "-updates", but that doesn't save you much.

Answer (score 1):

**1** .You can choose the type of updates from **Software & Updates**.

[image: img]

Adjust the settings to your needs!

**2**. Security is probably the most essential reason to always stay up to date.

**Unwanted updates** in your question I consider third-party updates being meant.

[image: img]

You can adjust this in the  **Other software** tab.

Comment: nice screenshots =)